# Gemfile.lock required. Please check it in

Tags: ruby, heroku

```
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 3.82 KiB | 1.91 MiB/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/NoLockfile
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Gemfile.lock required. Please check it in.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to aqueous-reaches-83684.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/aqueous-reaches-83684.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/aqueous-reaches-83684.git'
```

I want to launch my application on heroku

I always have one and the same mistake:

> Gemfile.lock required. Please check it in.

I did everything according to the instructions! Deleted, downloaded, does not work anyway

Used

```
bundle install
```

Still the same error

Comment: *"I did everything according to the instructions! Deleted, downloaded, does not work anyway"* -- That's not what the instructions say. It says "please check the `Gemfile.lock` in". The `Gemfile.lock` needs to be in source control. Make sure you don't have it included in the `.gitignore` file, and make sure it's added (`git add Gemfile.lock; git commit`).

Comment: (Assuming you are using github, for example) if you go onto the github repository right now, you will presumably see that the `Gemfile.lock` is **not** in the file list, because you haven't included it in source control.

Comment: If you provide full reproduction steps (what did you actually try? You said you "deleted and downloaded", but that's not what the error says) then it will hopefully become clear what the issue is.

Comment: The `Gemfile.lock` needs to be **pushed** to the **master** branch. That's what the error says, and that's what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add your Gemfile.lock to source control.

Considering you are on master branch:

```
git add Gemfile.lock
git commit -m "Commit Gemfile.lock"
git push heroku master
```

Otherwise:

```
git push heroku current_branch:master
```

If it doesn't work, you probably have it ignored in your `.gitignore` file.

Remove `Gemfile.lock` or `*.lock` from your ignored list and repeat the commands above.

Comment: Another thing that can happen is if OP is working from a branch then they're pushing the version from master. `git push heroku master` is actually shorthand for `git push heroku master:master` where the format is `git push heroku <from-branch>:<to-branch>` so for example if they're on the `foo` branch and want to deploy that they need to run `git push heroku foo:master`.

Comment: Thanks. I just added it to the answer.